# Importing XMLs programmatically from Java: items are imported but the returned list is empty

Tags: java, xml, intersystems-cache

This is a sample Java code which tries to use [`%SYSTEM.OBJ`'s `LoadStream` method](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25SYSTEM.OBJ#METHOD_LoadStream) to import the classes available in an XML export; `import` directives have been omitted for "brevity":

```
public final class Main2
{
    private static final String CACHEDB_HOST = "cachedb.host";
    private static final String CACHEDB_PORT = "cachedb.port";
    private static final String CACHEDB_USER = "cachedb.user";
    private static final String CACHEDB_PASSWORD = "cachedb.password";
    private static final String CACHEDB_NAMESPACE = "cachedb.namespace";
    private static final String LOADEDFILE = "loadedFile";

    private static final String CACHEDB_HOST_DEFAULT = "localhost";
    private static final String CACHEDB_PORT_DEFAULT = "1972";

    private static final String JDBC_URL_TEMPLATE = "jdbc:Cache://%s:%s/%s";

    private Main2()
    {
        throw new Error("instantiation not permitted");
    }

    public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException, CacheException
    {
        if (args.length == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("missing arguments");

        final Properties properties = new Properties();

        final Path path = Paths.get(args[0]).toRealPath();

        try (
            final Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path);
        ) {
            properties.load(reader);
        }

        final String jdbcUrl = String.format(JDBC_URL_TEMPLATE,
            readProperty(properties, CACHEDB_HOST, CACHEDB_HOST_DEFAULT),
            readProperty(properties, CACHEDB_PORT, CACHEDB_PORT_DEFAULT),
            readProperty(properties, CACHEDB_NAMESPACE));

        final String user = readProperty(properties, CACHEDB_USER);
        final String password = readProperty(properties, CACHEDB_PASSWORD);

        final Path loadedFile = Paths.get(readProperty(properties, LOADEDFILE))
            .toRealPath();

        try (
            final CacheDb db = new CacheDb(jdbcUrl, user, password);
        ) {
            final GlobalCharacterStream stream
                = new GlobalCharacterStream(db.getDatabase());

            loadContent(stream, loadedFile);

            /*
             * Arguments for class "%SYSTEM.OBJ", class method "LoadStream"
             */
            final Dataholder[] arguments = new Dataholder[8];

            /*
             * Arguments ByRef
             *
             * Indices start at 1, not 0
             */
            final int[] byRefArgs = new int[2];

            // Arg 3: error log
            final StringHolder errorlog = new StringHolder("");
            byRefArgs[0] = 3;

            // Arg 4: list of loaded items
            final StringHolder loadedlist = new StringHolder("");
            byRefArgs[1] = 4;

            /*
             * Fill arguments
             */
            // arg 1: stream
            arguments[0] = Dataholder.create(stream);
            // arg 2: qspec; the default, therefore null
            arguments[1] = new Dataholder((String) null);
            // arg 3: errorlog
            arguments[2] = Dataholder.create(errorlog.value);
            // arg 4: loadedlist
            arguments[3] = Dataholder.create(loadedlist.value);
            // arg 5: listonly; we want true
            arguments[4] = Dataholder.create(Boolean.TRUE);
            // arg 6: selecteditems; nothing
            arguments[5] = Dataholder.create(null);
            // arg 7: displayname. For logging...
            arguments[6] = Dataholder.create("IMPORT");
            // arg 8: charset. Default is empty string, we'll assume UTF-8.
            arguments[7] = new Dataholder((String) null);

            // Now, make the call
            final Dataholder[] result = db.getDatabase().runClassMethod(
                "%SYSTEM.OBJ",
                "LoadStream",
                byRefArgs,
                arguments,
                Database.RET_PRIM
            );

            /*
             * The result normally has three members:
             *
             * - first is the status; and we need to do that:
             */
            db.getDatabase().parseStatus(result[0]);

            /*
             * - others are ByRef arguments
             */
            // FIXME: probably not ideal
            errorlog.set(result[1].getString());
            System.out.println("errorlog: " + errorlog.getValue());

            loadedlist.set(result[2].getString());
            System.out.println("loadedlist: " + loadedlist.getValue());
        }
    }

    private static void loadContent(final GlobalCharacterStream stream,
        final Path path)
        throws IOException, CacheException
    {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try (
            final Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path);
        ) {
            final char[] buf = new char[2048];
            int nrChars;

            while ((nrChars = reader.read(buf)) != -1)
                sb.append(buf, 0, nrChars);
        }

        stream._write(sb.toString());
    }

    private static String readProperty(final Properties properties,
        final String key)
    {
        final String ret = properties.getProperty(key);
        if (ret == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("required property " + key
                + " is missing");
        return ret;
    }

    private static String readProperty(final Properties properties,
        final String key, final String defaultValue)
    {
        return properties.getProperty(key, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

Now, the code runs; in Studio, I see that the items are imported as well.

However the output is this (the caché install is in French, sorry):

```
Inventaire démarré le 02/12/2016 11:16:38
Classement du fichier IMPORT en tant que xml
Inventaire terminé.

errorlog: 
loadedlist: null
```

I cannot see which items have been imported.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you change `LoadStream` to `Load` and give real path to file, you will see that `loadedlist` works fine. Output log, should show what was imported, and exactly the same items should be in an list, but nothing shown in output log.

Comment: @DAiMor well, the goal here is that the Caché installation _may not be_ on the machine on which this code is run. Therefore I can't use `Load`.

Comment: Unfortunately, such connection does not support arrays as a value, and you can't get data from such value. `Load` works, because Caché code converts array to list of values, and then only this list available in Java.

Comment: @DAiMor what do you mean by "such connection"? The fact that the file is not local or something else?

Comment: I just mean Java binding to Caché, not sure that it will be possible in any other bindings on any languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java bindings supports getting ByRef values, and you do it correct. But unfortunately there is one limitations, and you catch it here. With ByRef in Caché we can pass arrays, such like below

```
array("name1")="value1"
array("name2")="value2"
```

But in Java we can't get such value, only if array was have value in a "root". `Load` method in a meanwhile, has code which transform array to list of values, and such value we already can get. So, as a workaround I can recommend to replace `%GlobalCharacterStream` to `%FileCharacterStream`, with some temporary filename with extension `xml`. And then we can use this filename in a `Load` method. So, after few changes, code should looks like:

```
    final FileCharacterStream stream = new FileCharacterStream(db);

    Dataholder[] args = new Dataholder[]{new Dataholder("xml")};
    Dataholder res = ((SysDatabase) db).runClassMethod("%File", "TempFilename", args, 0);
    stream._filenameSet(res.getString());

    loadContent(stream, path);

    final String remoteFileName = stream._filenameGet();


    /*
     * Arguments for class "%SYSTEM.OBJ", class method "Load"
     */
    final Dataholder[] arguments = new Dataholder[9];

    /*
     * Arguments ByRef
     *
     * Indices start at 1, not 0
     */
    final int[] byRefArgs = new int[3];

    // Arg 3: error log
    final StringHolder errorlog = new StringHolder("");
    byRefArgs[0] = 3;

    // Arg 4: list of loaded items
    final StringHolder loadedlist = new StringHolder("");
    byRefArgs[1] = 4;

    // Arg 9: description (?)
    final StringHolder description = new StringHolder("");
    byRefArgs[2] = 9;

    /*
     * Fill arguments
     */
    // arg 1: file name
    arguments[0] = Dataholder.create(remoteFileName);
    // arg 2: qspec; we want to ensure that compile works, at least
    arguments[1] = new Dataholder("d");
    // arg 3: errorlog
    arguments[2] = Dataholder.create(errorlog.value);
    // arg 4: loadedlist
    arguments[3] = Dataholder.create(loadedlist.value);
    // arg 5: listonly; no
    arguments[4] = Dataholder.create(Boolean.FALSE);
    // arg 6: selecteditems; nothing
    arguments[5] = Dataholder.create(null);
    // arg 7: displayname. For logging...
    arguments[6] = Dataholder.create("IMPORT.xml");
    // arg 8: charset. Default is empty string, we'll assume UTF-8.
    arguments[7] = new Dataholder((String) null);
    // arg 9: description (?)
    arguments[8] = Dataholder.create(description.value);

    // Now, make the call
    final Dataholder[] result = db.runClassMethod(
        "%SYSTEM.OBJ",
        "Load",
        byRefArgs,
        arguments,
        Database.RET_PRIM
    );

    /*
     * The result normally has three members:
     *
     * - first is the status; and we need to do that:
     */
    db.parseStatus(result[0]);

    /*
     * - others are ByRef arguments
     */
    errorlog.set(result[1].getString());
    System.out.println("errorlog: " + errorlog.getValue());

    loadedlist.set(result[2].getString());
    System.out.println("loadedlist: " + loadedlist.getValue());
```

and as a result

```
 Load started on 02/12/2016 22:56:06
 Loading file IMPORT.xml as xml
 Imported class: Sample.Address
 Imported class: Sample.Person
 Load finished successfully.

 errorlog: 
 loadedlist: Sample.Address.cls,Sample.Person.cls
```